# postgresql match string against list

Tags: postgresql

Assuming I have this table and I am trying to match a substring from my columns (col) such as 'aa' to a list or array ('aaa, bbb, 'ccc', 'aab'), how would I go about doing this?

I have tried these with no results from the query when I am expecting at least 1 row that contains 'aa' in column col:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aab');
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col = ANY(ARRAY['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aab']);
```

Any way to make a query equivalent to the python statement:

```
if any('aa' in item for item in ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aab']):
```

To return the row matching?

Comment: "no luck" isn't a valid Postgres error message. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I edited it, I did not get a return on the row that contains 'aa' in col

Comment: Well, obviously not. You are only looking for `'aaa'` which is a different value than `'aa'`

Comment: I would like my col string 'aa' to match anything within that list. For example, a python if statement:  if any('aa' in item for item in ['aaa', 'bbb']) would be true.

Comment: `select * from my_table where position(col in ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY['ccc','bbb','aaa'],','))>0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from my_table 
where position(col in ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY['ccc','bbb','aaa'],','))>0;
```

- `SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY['ccc','bbb','aaa'],',');` will return a string "ccc,bbb,aaa"
- `POSITION("aa" in "ccc,bbb,aaa")` will return the position of "aa" in that string.

EDIT: An alternative way (how many postgresql functions can I use in one statement):

```
select col 
from my_table
cross join (
   select s[x] as value 
   from (select  ARRAY['ccc','bbb','aaa']::text[] s) t 
   cross join generate_series(1,array_length(ARRAY['ccc','bbb','aaa'],1)) x
) a
where position(col in a.value)>0;
```

The sub-query will generate a table `a`, with column `value`, which contains all the values of the table.

There is a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c47f50ae35701165eb67e47ac37e72e4) of both queries.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the solution and explanation @Luuk